# Typescript Generics (or some other way) to get right typing for unknown array of objects

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript-generics, apollo, apollo-client

I am generating GraphQL (Apollo) queries (and mutations) dynamically from an array of objects. This function also returns some default queries. Something like this:

```
const DEFAULT_QUERY_1 = gql`
  query DefaultQuery1 {
    defaultQuery1 {
      ...Response
    }
  }
`

interface Item {
  key: string
}

function generateQueries(items: Item[]) {
  return {
    ...DEFAULT_QUERY_1,
    ...items.reduce((acc, { key }) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [`MY_DYNAMIC_${key.toUpperCase()}`]: gql`
          query MyDynamic${key} {
            myDynamic${key} {
              count
            }
          }
        `
      }
    )
  }
}
```

This is a pretty simplified code for the function which generates the `queries`.

And its usage is something like:

```
// Generating the queries
const items: Item[] = [{ key: 'test_1' }, { key: 'test_2' }]
export const QUERIES = generateQueries(kinds)
```

So then cn be consumed at some Component in the App tree, like:

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client"
import { QUERIES } from "./queries"

function Comp() {
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERIES.MY_DYNAMIC_TEST_1) // here is the point
}
```

Getting: `Property 'MY_DYNAMIC_TEST_1' does not exist on type '{ DEFAULT_QUERY_1: DocumentNode; }'.ts(2339)`

The point is that when consuming `QUERIES` I only having available the static/default one (called `DEFAULT_QUERY_1` in this example) and not the other two dynamically generated. The behaviour besides this TS issue, is working as expected in the app.

I started trying Generics but found two issues. When assigning a generic like `<I extends Item>` won't allows me to pass the array of `items` or typeof `items` in some way, something like `generateQueries<typeof kinds>(kinds)`. This works changing generics into `<I extends Item[]>`

But I thing the point is that in both cases what is returning isn't enough. Inferred types, returns only the default queries.

What is the way to have both, generic queries (inferred or not) and the ones generated from the array?

[Here](https://tsplay.dev/mLOrbN) is a TS Playground.

Below is showing that the default queries are suggested by ts code editor but this isn't happening for those dynamics (like `MY_DYNAMIC_TEST_x` queries).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I wrote something that may work for you, but without more information on what the specific types you want for the return value, it's not possible to write a complete answer. Check the code [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAaP1m) and get back to me with missing details. Then I can write an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @mocha for your playground. I made some changes to align to my code and errors I am having (ie: the "overload" for the function "generateQueries" declared two times in your case). Created the type for what is returned (doesn't matter the "something else", since in the code is DocumentNode coming from @apollo/client).

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mLOrbN) is the code updated. You will notice that QUERIES.MY_DYNAMIC_TEST_1 | 2 pass without errors, but isn't suggested as before (in your code).

Comment: In the impl. which allows only "DYNAMIC_TEST…" but without suggestions I am seeing this when hover over the QUERIES delcaration: `[x: `MY_DYNAMIC_${Uppercase<string>}`]: DocumentNode;` which I think is why isn't pointing to the items (from array). Any insight?